# Pandas If does not contain period keep the same, if contains period keep everything to the right

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a pandas dataframe with one column.  I would like to keep the rows the same if they do not have a `.` in them but if they do contain a period I would only like to keep anything to the right of the period.

```
df
   col1
0  learn
1  media
2  email.kg
3  tracking1
4  link.mta2
5  schemas
6  email.lg
7  secure2
8  tags
9  links.seminars
```

Desired outcome:

```
df1
   col1
0  learn
1  media
2  kg
3  tracking1
4  mta2
5  schemas
6  lg
7  secure2
8  tags
9  seminars
```

Comment: `df.col1.str.split('.').str[-1]` ?

Comment: or if it is just one columns, you can also opt for a list comprehension, which may be faster : `df['col1']=[i.split('.')[-1] for i in df['col1']]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try `split` and `ffill`:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.split('\.', expand=True).ffill(1)[-1]
```

Output:

```
    col1
0   learn
1   media
2   kg
3   tracking1
4   mta2
5   schemas
6   lg
7   secure2
8   tags
9   seminars
```

Comment: I was getting a `KeyError: -1` with the [-1], so I changed it to [1] and gave me the result I expected.  Thank you @Quang Hoang

Comment: Thanks, [1] only works if you have at most one `.` in each cell.  I was going for `.iloc[:,-1]`. But if `1` works for you, then `1` it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apply` method to call a function on each element of the column (which is called a `Serie` in pandas). In this function, you can use the `split` method, which will scan the string and break it at every occurence of `.`. The result of `split` is an array with one element for each string section delimited by `.`. Assuming you have at most one `.`, getting the last element of the array will work.

```py
df["col1"].apply(lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation?

Comment: The lambda function splits string at "." and take the right most split. apply runs the function for all rows